# Is there any broadcastReceiver to trigger my app in iOS when the app is not running?

Tags: ios

I need broadcastreceiver that to check changing internet connection and then trigger app for İOS app . it always runs like android .I tried NSNotificationCenter with Reacable library.But it only works when app is active  or background.it doesnt work whe application is not running.what am I do?
is there any  way for do this ?

Answer (score 1):

iOS does not have a (public) means of remotely starting an app. If there's a hidden way, any app using it would not be accepted by Apple for App Store publication.

Comment: I got it ,thank you.İn addition ,I have few questions .Not starting app only send notification  when internet connection is avaiable .is it possipble ?.
with Apple push notification server , can I send notification the  phone daily or check   phone have a internet connection ?